# By click on icon hide first parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

On click delete icon how can i remove first parent? I mean div with class box. I try everything and I haven't come to the solution yet

```js
var deleteIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-icon');
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

deleteIcon.forEach(function(icon) {
        icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
            box.style.display = "none";
            // icon.style.display = "none";            
        });
    });
```

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.delete-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">1</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">1</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">1</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">1</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">1</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">1</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't link to your code at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question is meaningless. Include your code in a code snippet, right here in your question as I've done for you. Also, always provide the code that you've tried so we can see if you are on the right track. Just saying I've tried everything doesn't help, since you clearly haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `box.style.display = "none";` doesn't work is because you defined `box` as being the return value from a `.querySelectorAll()` call. `.querySelectorAll()` returns a node list, which doesn't have a `.style` property. You must style an individual element, not a collection of elements.

Instead, just find the correct element with the [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method and then apply a pre-made CSS class to it.

```js
var deleteIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-icon');
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

deleteIcon.forEach(function(icon) {
        icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Find the nearest ancestor that matches the selector
            // and add the hidden class to it.
            this.closest("div.box").classList.add("hidden");      
        });
    });
```

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.delete-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">Box 1</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">Box 2</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">Box 3</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">Box 4</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">Box 5</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <ul class="nothing">
     <li class="blabla">Box 6</li>
     <li class="blabla">2</li>
     <li class="blabla">3</li>
     <li class="blabla">4</li>
     <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>nothing1</div>
  <div>nothing2</div>
  <div>nothing3</div>
  
  
  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select parent element by `element` object's `parentElement` property.

And to delete use 'remove' or `removeChild` method.

```js
var deleteIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-icon');
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

deleteIcon.forEach(function(icon) {
  icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let parent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}

.icon-test {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #f99;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.delete-icon {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.delete-icon::before {
  content: '\00D7';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
  <ul class="nothing">
    <li class="blabla">1</li>
    <li class="blabla">2</li>
    <li class="blabla">3</li>
    <li class="blabla">4</li>
    <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>box 1</div>


  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <ul class="nothing">
    <li class="blabla">1</li>
    <li class="blabla">2</li>
    <li class="blabla">3</li>
    <li class="blabla">4</li>
    <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>box 2</div>

  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <ul class="nothing">
    <li class="blabla">1</li>
    <li class="blabla">2</li>
    <li class="blabla">3</li>
    <li class="blabla">4</li>
    <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>box 3</div>


  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <ul class="nothing">
    <li class="blabla">1</li>
    <li class="blabla">2</li>
    <li class="blabla">3</li>
    <li class="blabla">4</li>
    <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>box 4</div>


  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <ul class="nothing">
    <li class="blabla">1</li>
    <li class="blabla">2</li>
    <li class="blabla">3</li>
    <li class="blabla">4</li>
    <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>box 5</div>


  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <ul class="nothing">
    <li class="blabla">1</li>
    <li class="blabla">2</li>
    <li class="blabla">3</li>
    <li class="blabla">4</li>
    <span>bla bla</span>
  </ul>
  <div>box 6</div>


  <div class="icon-test">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```